# C# Unit Test: How to create test input of COM Interop value?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, com-interop, directoryservices

In my application, there is a method which accepts an `Object`, then performs some operations on it to return a C# `long` value. At runtime, the `Object` received from Active Directory is an `IADSLargeInteger`.

In writing a unit test for this code, I am unable to create such an object to pass into the method being tested.

How can I create such an object for my unit test?
Are there other ways to verify the logic of my method?

Method to be tested:

```cs
public static long ConvertLargeIntegerToLong(object largeInteger)
{
    var type = largeInteger.GetType();
    var highPart = (int)type.InvokeMember("HighPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, largeInteger, null)!;
    var lowPartInt = (int)type.InvokeMember("LowPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Public, null, largeInteger, null)!;
    uint lowPartUint;
    unchecked
    {
        lowPartUint = (uint)lowPartInt;
    }
    return (long)highPart << 32 | (long)lowPartUint;
}
```

Sample Unit Test

```cs
public void ConvertLargeIntegerToLong_ComObjectLargeInt_Long()
{
    var expectedValue = 94294967295;
    var testValue = ??; // What to put here? 
    var result = ConvertLargeIntegerToLong(testValue);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, result);
}
```

Comment: remove `| BindingFlags.Public` and use anonymous class `var testValue = new {HighPart = intvalue, LowPart = intvalue} ;`

Comment: Copy/paste [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/ADMembershipProvider.cs,4618) to create your own IAdsLargeInteger interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking the question, I continued hunting around and thought to add the `activeds.dll` as a COM reference to my test project.

After I did that, I had direct access to the `IADSLargeInteger` interface. And looking more closely at the Microsoft docs for the interface, saw an example creating such an object for VB.Net.

In the end, I did like this for my code (still maintaining the COM reference):

```cs
var testValue = new LargeInteger { HighPart = 1234, LowPart = 4567 };
```

`LargeInteger` is also in that DLL and is the concrete class implementing the interface -- as **@Hans Passant** mentioned in his comment.